# All the text goes blank when WPF app(v4.0) runs on spanish window7(64 bit)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-4.0

In the window there is a textbox with text set in xaml only. code behind file has no logic. in that case, when the application starts , the textbox is empty.
Any reasons for it??

Comment: What does the XAML look like? And is this Silverlight or WPF?

Comment: It just contains one textblock with some text say "Test".

Comment: Are there `xml:lang` tags? Does AssemblyInfo.cs contain an `AssemblyCulture` or `NeutralResourcesLanguage` attribute?

Comment: xml:lang i have tried, no use. NeutralResourcesLanguage was set to en-US still no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is a font substitution issue.   If the particular font family used in the application is not present in any form on the destination OS then there may not be an appropriate font replacement for the application to render with.    What typeface are you using for the text?  Have you considered one of the default typefaces which ship with Windows?

Comment: I haven't used any fancied font or something. Just created a normal app without any font changes. I am working with the default of the application. Haven't changed anything.